# How to get the frame of UIBarButtonItem with respect to UIWindow in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uiwindow

I have gone through a lot of SO posts on this topic. But I have a different requirement.

Am working on an **App Walkthrough** page in my app for which i would like to display some hints over some of the UI objects. I would like to place a UIView above the entire page to blur it out and then display highlighted image and a hint text. For that reason, I need the frame of those objects(for which help is required) with respect to the UIWindow so that i can place another highlighted image exactly above them. I have found the frame of a couple of objects inside the header of a tableview with the following code.

```
//Hint for expand/collapse arrow
guard let deviceHeaderView: StatusSectionView = tblStatus.headerView(forSection: 0) as? StatusSectionView else {
    //Hide expand/collapse hint objects
}

if let imgExpandCollapseFrame = deviceHeaderView.imgExpandCollapse.superview?.convert(deviceHeaderView.imgExpandCollapse.frame, to: window) {
    print("Frame of imgExpandCollapse.. \(imgExpandCollapseFrame)")

    let xPosition = (imgExpandCollapseFrame.origin.x + (imgExpandCollapseFrame.size.width/2)) - appWalkthroughView.downArrowHintImgView.frame.size.width/2

    let yPosition = (imgExpandCollapseFrame.origin.y + (imgExpandCollapseFrame.size.height/2)) - appWalkthroughView.downArrowHintImgView.frame.size.height/2

    appWalkthroughView.downArrowHintImgView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition,
                                                           y: yPosition,
                                                           width: appWalkthroughView.downArrowHintImgView.frame.size.width,
                                                           height: appWalkthroughView.downArrowHintImgView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Similarly, I need to find the frame of the UIBarButtonItem and convert its frame with respect to the UIWindow and display hint image above it.

For that, I have found the frame of the UIBarButtonItem like this,

```
let leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!

if let leftBarButtonItemView = leftBarButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
    print(leftBarButtonItemView.frame)
}
```

This code just gives the bounds of the bar button item like this.

```
(0.0, 0.0, 36.0, 44.0)
```

And i couldn't convert its frame with respect to UIWindow. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
let leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
        if let leftBarButtonItemView = leftBarButtonItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
            //You should ask your window to convert your frame to his frames.
            if let rect = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.convert(leftBarButtonItemView.frame, from: nil) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the view to do the conversion for you:

```
let frameInWindow = leftBarButtonItemView.convert(leftBarButtonItemView.bounds, to: nil)
```

(convert will use the widow's coordinate system is the target view is nil)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. One precondition for the coordinate transformation to work is that the views (in this case `leftBarButtonItemView` and the application's key window) must be part of the same view hierarchy (i.e. the `leftBarButtonItemView` must be a descendant of the window in the view hierarchy somehow). This may not be the case if the UINavigationBar or the view controller is not currently being displayed.